# Confused with how lightning record pages work

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, flexipages

1. I logged in as System Admin and switch to app named "Acme Console"(blurred the actual name in screenshot but let's just assume that is the app name).
2. I navigate to Order record detail page and click on setup icon and select "Edit Page" option and this is what I see. It tells me that I am on Lightning record page named "**Order_Record_Page1**".

   [image]
3. I go to setup screen and see what all lightning pages are there for order object and I don't see a page named "**Order_Record_Page1**". Here is the screenshot.

   [image]
4. I tried the option page assignments to see which lightning page is assigned for System Admin profile when using Acme console app and it doesn't show the page name but just says "System Default".

   [image]

My question is if I don't see a Lightning record page named "Order_Record_Page1" in step 3, why does it say that I am editing "Order_Record_Page1" in step 2.

**EDIT**:
This is what I see when I query `FlexiPage` object in developer console using Tooling API and it shows that there is no FlexiPage named **Order_Record_Page1**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Order_Record_Page1' doesn't exist in the database until you press save. What you are seeing is technically a cloned version of the standard (system default) out of the box page, all in your browser. "Order_Record_Page1" is a default generated name which will be used if you press save.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing DeveloperName with Label. Most Salesforce setup objects have a DeveloperName which needs to be unique and can't contain spaces or special characters, whereas the Label can contain those things.

If you open developer console and run a query using the Tooling API, you can see both pretty easily.

`select id, MasterLabel, DeveloperName from flexipage`

Comment: I queried `FlexiPage` object as you said for Order object and it shows only one record and the developername is different than what I see in step 2. I updated question with more details.

Comment: Have you ever saved the page? I think what is happening is that there is an out of the box page that is read only. When you click edit, it creates a new version and appends the `1`. Looking in my org at Account, I have one page I can't edit.

Comment: No, I didn’t save the page. But I think the same, when we do the Edit page from setup, it is creating a new page appened with “1”.

Comment: What Daniel is saying is correct. 'Order_Record_Page1' doesn't exist in the database until you press save. What you are seeing is technically a cloned version of the standard out of the box page, all in your browser. "Order_Record_Page1" is a default generated name which will be used if you press save.